# Why does the PHP documentation says that PHP does not support Unicode?

Tags: php

This [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) says the following:

> This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does
> not offer native Unicode support

But I can assign a UTF-8 string literal to a variable, for example:

```
$str = "γεια";
```

And I can use functions that work on UTF-8 strings, for example:

```
echo mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
```

So why does the PHP documentation says that PHP does not support Unicode?

Comment: Did you click the link that takes you to [details of the string type](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details)?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation does not say that PHP doesn't support Unicode. It says it doesn't offer **native** Unicode support.

That is, simple operations that do not require support for multi-byte characters (assigning or outputting strings, for example) will work, but anything that requires an awareness of multi-byte characters won't work. The existence of the `mb_*()` functions provides a work-around for many of the limitations, but does not imply *"native"* support. You'll find a fuller discussion of the issues on the [PHP web site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details)

FWIW, PHP6 was first conceived as a version that included native support for Unicode. The problems arising became so intractable that it was abandoned.

Comment: You can extend this to say "PHP does not support _any_ particular character set or encoding". Aside from some defaults for the aforementioned charset-aware functions, PHP does not care if the data is in UTF8/16, ISO-8859-1, SHIFT-JIS, EBDIC, etc. It will deliver its input reliably to its destination, but it's up to _you_ to make it your business to care that that data is handled properly according to its encoding throughout your application. This may be otherwise known as "binary strings" or "byte arrays".